# Java: how to pass a variable from one class to another using access modifiers

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm brand new to java, and have experience doing this in C# but something seems different. I am trying to make the input from the user be passed to the set method for the variable in another class.

//this is the class im trying to pass the variable to

```
public class HealthProfile
{
    private String name="";
    private double age;
    private double weight;
    private double height;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

// this is the method im trying to pass the value from taking the users input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1Main {
    public void getInput()
    {

        HealthProfile user = new HealthProfile();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        user.setName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Your Age:  ");
        user.setAge(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.print("Your Weight:  ");
        user.setWeight(Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: read about java coding styleguides. "_" is only used for CONSTANT_NAMES (or number literals), but has otherwise no place in java source code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax:

```
user.setName(aName)= input.nextLine();
```

should be

```
user.setName(input.nextLine());
```

for example. In Java, there is no such thing as a "named parameter"; when you call methods, you simply have to provide the parameters simply "in place", in the exact same order as specified in the method declaration.

And a word on the title of your question: access modifiers do only control which fields/methods can be **accesses** from other classes; you cannot "use" them to pass anything.